# Linking issue with eosio-ld

Tags: smartcontracts, eos

I'm trying to build my EOS smart contract using eosio.cdt and via cmake.
Compilation succeeded, but linking failed with below log.

```
/usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/wasm-ld: error: locale.cpp.o: undefined symbol: strftime_l
/usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/wasm-ld: error: memory.cpp.o: undefined symbol: __cxa_pure_virtual
/usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/wasm-ld: error: system_error.cpp.o: undefined symbol: __cxa_pure_virtual
```

The code for linking module generated by cmake is as below.

```
eosio-ld -L=/usr/local/eosio.cdt/lib/ CMakeFiles/a.wasm.dir/a.cpp.o CMakeFiles/a.wasm.dir/validator/b.cpp.o CMakeFiles/a.wasm.dir/validator/c.cpp.o CMakeFiles/a.wasm.dir/common/d.cpp.o -o a.wasm
```

libc++.a exists in /usr/local/eosio.cdt/lib/.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just include `<eosiolib/eosio.hpp>` header file.

Comment: Do you have any class/struct that defines pure virtual function?
This error can also occur if you include standard library header files which define classes with virtual interfaces.  Example of such header file would be `iostream`

Comment: The error is raised if "std::regex re("");" is included in my contract method.
Can't std::regex be used in eos contracts?

Comment: I haven't used `std::regex` in the EOS wasm so I don't know the correct answer. But I'd say that if including `regex` caused the undefined error then `std::regex` cannot be used in the contract.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I’ll try another way.